# Inheritance anomaly in C++ and concurrent programming

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am reading about concurrent programming. Here it is mentioned about inheritance anomaly problem.

Inheritance anomaly is mentioned in following article on Active object pattern on page 4.

http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Act-Obj.pdf

Can any one mention what is inheritance anomaly problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the next few pages of your text to see if this term is explained ?

Comment: Did you try google? I get plenty of results on it.

Comment: I tried google but I didn't get in simple terms.

Comment: @bames53 I did try google, and I can say venkysmarty has a point. Additionally, there is no question on SO yet with "inheritance anomaly" in the title, so this question does belong here. venkysmarty: It would help, though, if you could try to share what you understood about the term "inheritance anomaly" from your book.

Comment: 2nd hit on google for me: http://wisnesky.net/anomaly.pdf section 1.1 there, I don't think this can be exaplained any clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to occur from back in 1993 when they thought that inheritance for code re-use was a good idea.

It usually isn't. It wasn't then but they thought it was.

Inheritance should be for polymorphic behaviour. Templates or generics or composition should be used for code-reuse.

The main article seems to be [this one](http://wisnesky.net/anomaly.pdf)

Comment: One could just as easily argue that the problem is due to trying to synchronize at too low a level.  There are occasions where inheritance for code re-use is a good idea (e.g. mixins), but they aren't legion, and they're almost always at a level below what you'd want to synchronize.  Similarly, there are a few cases where synchronization at such a low level is appropriate, but they aren't legion, and they almost always occur with very simple objects.